# Move relative to the end of line in Vim

Tags: vim

Imagine I have a sentence like this:

```
Block chain, the decentralised public ledger that records transactions on the bitcoin network.
```

And if my cursor is at the end of the first word, is there a way to move relative to the end of the sentence rather than from the cursor position? Think of something like, the first `c` from right hand side is where I want to go, is there a way to reach rather than going to the end first and using `F` to reach the `c` (`$Fc`).

Comment: why don't you want to use `$Fc`? what's your concern?

Comment: @Kent, too many keystrokes?

Comment: No, I don't think its too many keystrokes. I just imagined existence of multiple initial positions to invoke a search, like: `start_of_line`, `cursor_position`, `end_of_line`; seemed sensible to be able to switch those easily; and then do the jumps. I was hoping for something like this: `<C-e>fc` so that jumps always happen using `f` but direction keeps changing depending on the setting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Vim has (an abundance of) motions that move relative to the current (cursor) position: `l`, `w`, `f` among them. And you can re-position the cursor easily with many motions: `^`, `0`, `$`, `gm`. When combined, that means you can reach almost any place with just a few keystrokes, and it's possible to remember each of those quite easily.

Given that there's a limit to available keys (and that Vim out of the box already uses most of them!), and a limit to what you can memorize, I think that's a perfect balance. In that light, I think `$Fc` is nothing to worry about (just compare with other editors!)

If that particular motion's inefficiency bothers you, you can always write a custom mapping (and assign one of the few available keys), but that doesn't scale well.

Comment: I totally agree, somehow had this lingering thought that something like that exists. Btw, whats `gm`?

Comment: Try it out (on a long line), or `:help gm`!

Answer (score 1):

If you think `$Fc` 3 keystrokes is too many......

operator + target char have already 2 strokes. 
We can dynamic capture the target char. But to make it 2 strokes, we have to scarify a normal mode key, I don't know which one you don't use, I just cannot find one on my keyboard, so as example I use the `<F6>` you can change it as you like.

This mapping allows you press `<F6>c` to that place, of course, `c` could be any character.

```
nnoremap <expr> <space> '$F'. nr2char(getchar())
```

And this won't work if the target char, i.e (`c`) is at the EOL. Well you can do further checking, e.g. write your own function to do it, if you think it is really necessary.

Personally I don't think it is worthwhile. Just get used to the `$Fx`.